# Styling HTML/CSS to Achieve the Given Effect

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I'm using [fancyBox3](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) in a project and I want to achieve the following:

[image: This display of images]

I wanted to know if there is a CSS trick to achieve it or if it requires some math and calculation to make it fit perfectly?

Comment: You might want to show attempts of doing it by yourself, as for we can't help you with anything other than doing it for you …

Comment: [Please provide your question with code a minimal, clear and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there are two ways - using JS (there are ton of scripts, for example https://github.com/brunjo/rowGrid.js, https://haltu.github.io/muuri/, https://github.com/kombai/freewall, http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) or CSS.

The problem with CSS is that it is still not possible to create true "masonry style layout", but you can archive something similar, try googling for "masonry using css", you will find many articles and examples about this topic, for example, this one - https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/) - it does all the calculations for you to make your images tesselate as you resize the screen etc.